# Fixing git appended to file names

Tags: git, github, filenames

I had to work on a corrupted git repo recently, and after fixing it, many of my file names have been changed (ie. `file.txt` ->  `file (bf800a19).txt`; or `file.py` -> `file (418d7abf).py`)
I'm guessing that this is a number of which commit the file is from or something similar, but I cannot seem to find exactly what it is from.

I would really like a way to quickly strip and remove all of these renamings as my code will no longer run without editing all of the paths, and thought about writing a script to do so, but is there a git command that will quickly do this for me, and what do these codes mean? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Git checkout can do that:

```
$ git checkout -- ./
```

At the root of your repository, will remove every change not added to the index.

Git reset hard will remove every uncommitted change.

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't fix my file name issue.